# SQL Server OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql-server-2012, subquery, outer-join

[image: SQL Server JOIN interview question]

How to find the non matching records from both the tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to find out the not matching Id from both the tables and can combine it by `UNION ALL`.

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.[Id] FROM [table-1] t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM [table-2] t2
    WHERE t1.[Id] = t2.[Id]
)
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.[Id] FROM [table-2] t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM [table-1] t1
    WHERE t1.[Id] = t2.[Id]
);
```

[**Demo for reference**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/549020/finding-not-matching-records-from-two-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Another way with TOP 1 WITH TIES and COUNT OVER:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES  *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM [table-1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM [table-2]
) u
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id)
```

Output:

```
Id  name
D   ...
E   ...
F   ...
G   ...
H   ...
I   ...
J   ...
K   ...
```

`COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id)` Gives `1` to unique row and `>1` if there are duplicated `Id`s. If you put that to ORDER BY and add TOP 1 WITH TIES - that will left only `Id`s with minimal count.

Another way with FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(Id1,Id2) Id,
        COALESCE(name1,name2) name
FROM (
    SELECT  t1.Id Id1,
            t1.[name] name1,
            t2.Id Id2,
            t2.[name] name2
    FROM [table-1] t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN [table-2] t2
        ON t1.Id = t2.Id
    WHERE t1.Id IS NULL OR t2.ID IS NULL
) as t
```

Same output (with another order)